# Test connection with MongoDb using Spring Boot 2 with MongoTamplete

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I need to test periodically my connection with MongoDB, to do this I would like to use MongoTemplate.

How can I do this?

tks.

Comment: Don't... Spring Boot already has a health check for that, why not simply use that (just include the Sprign Boot Actuator in your project and get that automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring Boot Actuator for that. Include the Actuator dependency. In application.properties include  management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS. Now you should be able to see status of your Mongo Connection.